# Update Woocommerce status manually not with API

Tags: api, woocommerce

How can i update an order on woocommerce manually without api? Which fields need to be updated? Not getting the order to be set as completed.

Answer (score 0):

Change from order edit screen and click update.

[image]

Comment: I want to update the order via a script. through a different side but not use API.